# Obj-C, iOS, how do I convert a navigation-based app in to a view-based app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I've discovered that I need to show views with animation transition effects and don't need to stack views. How do I convert my app to view-based rather from the navigation-based ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you know the answer already ;-) rewrite it step by step. It's probably a lot of work, but there is no automated script or anything else which will do the work for you.

If your project is not that large, you can just create a new View Based Application template and insert your classes and interface files and configure anything else to make it work.